# Julia: Referencing struct composed of other struct definitions

Tags: julia

I have a user-defined structure:

```
using Parameters

@with_kw struct TypeSingle
    id::Int
    x::Union{Int32, Missing} = missing
    flag::Bool = true
end

@with_kw struct TypeAll
    A = TypeSingle(id=01,x=0.1,flag=false)
    B = TypeSingle(id=02)
    # this continues on until
    Z = TypeSingle(id=26,x=1.3)
end
```

I have some questions regarding operations that I would like to perform with `TypeAll`:

- I'd like to refer to each entry, A.id, B.id etc.. in the composite TypeAll in a loop that runs from the lowest id to the highest.
- Is there a way to extract the size of this type? i.e. how many A,B,...Z are there in total?
- Would this be better suited to a vector of TypeA? In my actual code TypeAll isn't only composed of TypeA, but also includes TypeB, TypeC etc..

Answer (score 2):

As long as your `TypeAll` is not going to be mutable, it looks a lot like a named tuple (`NamedTuple`) so why not use one instead of a `TypeAll`? e.g.

```
julia> t = (A = (01, 0.1, false), B = (02, missing, true), C = (26, 1.3, true))
(A = (1, 0.1, false), B = (2, missing, true), C = (26, 1.3, true))

julia> t[1]
(1, 0.1, false)

julia> length(t)
3

julia> sort(collect(t), lt = (x, y) -> x[1] < y[1])
3-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Any, Bool}}:
 (1, 0.1, 0)
 (2, missing, 1)
 (26, 1.3, 1)
```

If you want to have TypeAll mutable, I would use a vector of TypeSingle, instead of a named tuple.